# How to customize Grails default CRUD code templates (such as GSP, Controller, Service, and Specification templates) generated by scaffolding?

Tags: groovy, grails, gsp

I have a question that how can I display the controller CRUD default sites with an own stylesheet?

**Problem Context**

I created a grails application with a controller, domain, and a view and now I created my own stylesheet, own layout, and added some pages. Now I have my new files with my stylesheet but if I use the default function it looks the same:

[image: Default design]

So how can I use the CRUD function in the content of my new pages with my style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default scaffolding code is generated using the Grails Scaffolding plugin.

- If it is about the styles only then you could include the stylesheet in the main layout file.
- Otherwise, I think you could also extend the scaffolding templates using the `grails install-templates` to add the templates under the `src/main/templates/scaffolding` which you could customize as per the requirement.

You may also want to take a look at the Grails scaffolding plugin [here](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding)

Comment: If I add my stylesheet in the main layout file, I got the default nav from the main file in my content section of my pages.
How can I remove these?

Comment: You could remove the default navigation from the main layout.

Comment: But there is no navbar, I need to change it in the Grails scaffolding templates, but where are this template files?

Comment: In that case, you need to follow the second approach where you would execute `./grailsw install-temlplates` and then you can goto `src/main/templates/scaffolding` to update the corresponding page.